# Template to forms

Tags: python, forms, parsing, templates, jinja2

I'd like to do somehow the contrary to what a template is used for: I want to write templates and programmatically derive a representation of the different tags and placeholders present in the template, to ultimately generate a form.

To put it another way, when you usually have the data and populate the template with it, I want to have the template and ask the user the right data to fill it.

Example (with pseudo-syntax): `Hello {{ name_of_entity only-in ['World', 'Universe', 'Stackoverflow'] }}!`
**With that I could programatically derive that I should generate a form with a `select` tag named 'name_of_entity' and having 3 `options` ('World', 'Universe', 'Stackoverflow').**

I looked into Jinja2, and it seems I can reach my goal using it and extending it (even if it's made to do things the other way). But I am still unsure how I should do in some cases, eg.:

- if I want to represent that `{{ weekday }}` has values only in `['Mo', 'Tu', ...]`
- if I want to represent in the template that the `{{ amount }}` variable is accepting only integers...

Is Jinja a good base to reach these goals? If yes, how would you recommend to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Jinja makes sense for building this, in particular because it contains a full-on lexer and parser. You can leverage those to derive your own versions of this that do what you need.